New case of kept back packages without hold in Ubuntu 22.04
(NB this is not just missed dist-upgrade. So the question is not a plain duplicate.)
After upgrade to Ubuntu 22.04, I've started getting a strange situation when a package is declared "kept back" without a visible reason. Just now:
# apt-get dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  qemu-block-extra qemu-system-common qemu-system-data qemu-system-gui
  qemu-system-x86 qemu-utils

This had been happening with other packages a few days ago on another installation. I've checked hold mark on these packages, no one is present. Discover tool ignores them.
A wild guess about "verbose" mode just resulted in:
# apt-get dist-upgrade -V
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
   qemu-block-extra (1:6.2+dfsg-2ubuntu6.17 => 1:6.2+dfsg-2ubuntu6.18)
   qemu-system-common (1:6.2+dfsg-2ubuntu6.17 => 1:6.2+dfsg-2ubuntu6.18)
   qemu-system-data (1:6.2+dfsg-2ubuntu6.17 => 1:6.2+dfsg-2ubuntu6.18)
   qemu-system-gui (1:6.2+dfsg-2ubuntu6.17 => 1:6.2+dfsg-2ubuntu6.18)
   qemu-system-x86 (1:6.2+dfsg-2ubuntu6.17 => 1:6.2+dfsg-2ubuntu6.18)
   qemu-utils (1:6.2+dfsg-2ubuntu6.17 => 1:6.2+dfsg-2ubuntu6.18)
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 6 not upgraded.

Package versions seem properly increasing.
A direct request like apt-get install qemu-utils will fix it. But the situation confuses me. This apt-get install doesn't describe why the mass upgrade ignored the packages. Questions:

What factor results in this behavior? Is it a one-shot thing after release upgrade, or this is a regular behavior of the new release?

Is there a option (option set) to ask apt-get to describe in details why it saves a package from upgrade? (Even in a renowned case like a hold mark.)


UPD: It is suggested "phased updates" may be a reason, see the comments. This looks veracious.

@mook765 Seems very similar. Is another root cause possible here?

Did you review apt policy <packagename> for clues? Phasing (most likely) is clearly shown in apt policy output.

@user535733 Currently it has silently updated (without a question!) to new versions so I've missed the chance. Will check on a next occurence.

Confirmed for "policy": it shows notes like "(phased 40%)" on a new, temporary held, version.
